# Как правильно использовать SecureString?

Tags: c#, .net

Например, нужно захешировать пароль методом `string CalculateHash(string source)`. Но если я вытяну значение строки с SecureString в виде экземпляра класса `string` и передам его как атрибут, то эта строка попадёт в пул иинтернирования и будет лежать в памяти в открытом виде. Как бы правильно передать `SecureString` в метод `CalculateHash`, чтобы значение строки не осталось в памяти? Может можно каким-то образом использовать unsafe метод, который потом найдёт эту строку в адрессном пространстве приложения и затрёт её?

Comment: Это сделать невозможно. Любое преобразование `SecureString` в `string` теряет весь смысл его использования.

Comment: Не работайте со строками (как вариант). Работайте с массивами байт. Создали, поработали, очистили (_Array.Clear_). В _System.Security.Cryptography_ такое сплошь и рядом.

Answer (score 2):

В вашем случае никак. У вас должен быть отдельный метод специально для такого сценария. Например: `CalculateHash(SecureString source)` или `CalculateHash(IEnumerable<char> source)`

Comment: Нет. Со вторым я не согласен. Можно использовать от такой код:`var s = source.Aggregate((a, b) => $"{a}{b}");`

Comment: Ну или такой `var str = ""; fixed (char* ptr = source.ToArray()) { str += *ptr++; }`

Comment: @return имплементация метода должна подразумевать это, и не создавать строку в памяти. С таким же успехом метод может принимать на вход `SecureString` и внутри преобразовать его в обычную строку, в чем полностью убьет весь secure

Comment: "Т. к. защищённых строк нет в Windows, эти строки не такие уж и защищённые."

Comment: UPD: Но вы скажете "рефлексия". А скажу, что рефлексия расширяет возможности, а не сужает, как `SecureString` + рефлексия - затратный процесс, а "взлом" - нет. Если уж и "влаживаться" в secure, то юзать надо SHA256.

Comment: @return Что значит защищенных строк нет в Windows? Как раз в Windows они шифруются в памяти. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring?view=netframework-4.8#HowSecure `On the Windows operating system, the contents of a SecureString instance's internal character array are encrypted. `

Comment: "Если уж и "влаживаться" в secure, то юзать надо SHA256." - это и быстрее и в управляемом коде и т. д.

Comment: Вот именно - там хранится шифр (я так понимаю - хэш). Зачем юзать посредника, сужающего возможности, если можно юзать быструю хэш-функцию, делающую тоже самое?

Comment: @return так SHA256 однонаправленная хеш функция, как это автору поможет?) мы ведь не знаем, что делает его `CalculateHash`, может там что-то специфическое для его приложения. Где есть гарантии, что какая-то конкретная имплементация SHA256 очищает после себя память? Фишка SecureString защитить от пассивного чтения памяти во время работы приложения. Понятное дело, если ваше приложение запустили в отладке, там уже ничего не спасет.

Comment: Но, если каким-то образом на вашем компе есть зловред, который пытается незаметно во время работы сканировать память, то быстрое создание и уничтожение SecureString создаст проблемы для такого типа зловреда, так как уловить нужный момент будет сложно.

Comment: `Instead of using SecureString to protect passwords, the recommended alternative is to use an opaque handle to credentials that are stored outside of the process.` + По-моему это холивар и нам пора сворачиваться.

Comment: я согласен, мы ведь не знаем, что конкретно собирается делать автор

Answer (score 0):

[Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818704/how-to-convert-securestring-to-system-string) статья. Мне помогло.

---

Для ленивых:

```cs
String SecureStringToString(SecureString value) {
  IntPtr valuePtr = IntPtr.Zero;
  try {
    valuePtr = Marshal.SecureStringToGlobalAllocUnicode(value);
    return Marshal.PtrToStringUni(valuePtr);
  } finally {
    Marshal.ZeroFreeGlobalAllocUnicode(valuePtr);
  }
}
```

и

```
void HandleSecureString(SecureString value) {
  IntPtr valuePtr = IntPtr.Zero;
  try {
    valuePtr = Marshal.SecureStringToGlobalAllocUnicode(value);
    for (int i=0; i < value.Length; i++) {
      short unicodeChar = Marshal.ReadInt16(valuePtr, i*2);
      // handle unicodeChar
    }
  } finally {
    Marshal.ZeroFreeGlobalAllocUnicode(valuePtr);
  }
}
```

---

Т. к. защищённых строк нет в Windows, эти строки не такие уж и защищённые. Но делать так не рекомендую (как минимум потому что это не CLS Api). Тут как с методом финализации: юзать только если уж очень надо. Либо работайте со `string`, либо с `byte[]`, либо с `char[]`, либо перейдите [сюда](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography?view=netframework-4.8)